# I have error importing lodash in vue file

Tags: vuejs2, lodash

In my @vue/cli 4.0.5 app I'm trying to import the lodash library, after running 
`npm i lodash`

When I try to call `isEmpty` method I got this error:

```
Property or method "isEmpty" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Here's how I am importing it in my vue file :

```
<template>
    <article class="event_item_container">

        <span v-if="!isEmpty(example)">{{example}}</span>

        ...
    </article>
</template>

<script>
    import {bus} from '../../main'
    import axios from 'axios'

    import Vue from 'vue'

    import * as lodash from 'lodash'
    // Vue.use(lodash) // I tried uncomment this line the same error

    // import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty" // Aso I tried to uncomment this line, the same error
```

I tried to import into src/main.js file - the same error...

Which is the valid way?

Comment: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you can try.

1. Try adding

```
import lodash from 'lodash'; 
Vue.prototype._ = lodash
```

instead of `import * as lodash from 'lodash'`. Then try using `_.isEmpty`.

2. You can try importing `isEmpty` like

```
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
```

3. You can always trying uninstalling lodash (remove from `package.json`) and then run  `npm i --save lodash`

**EDIT**

As of NPM5 there is no difference between `npm install` and `npm install --save` since `npm install` now adds the package to `devDependencies`; something it did not do prior to NPM5 (this was why `npm install --save` was utilized).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please clarify point 3? Have I to reinstall the package with command npm i --save lodash  ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo I actually just did some research and it turns out since NPM5 `npm install` accomplishes what `npm install --save` used to do (adding the package to dev dependencies in package.json). If you're using NPM5+ `npm i` is fine. If you're using something lower then go ahead and use `npm install --save`. Uninstalling and re-installing still can't hurt but you just don't have to use `--save` if you're using npm5+

Answer (score 2):

Because you `import * as lodash from 'lodash'`, You have to use it like `!lodash.isEmpty(example)` instead of `!isEmpty(example)`.